# Returning multiple values in Ruby, to be used to call a function

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, capybara, incompatibility

Is it possible to return multiple values from a function?

I want to pass the return values into another function, and I wonder if I can avoid having to explode the array into multiple values

My problem?
I am upgrading Capybara for my project, and I realized, thanks to [CSS 'contains' selector & upgrade of Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937009/css-contains-selector-upgrade-of-capybara), that the statement below will no longer work

```
has_selector?(:css, "#rightCol:contains(\"#{page_name}\")")
```

I want to get it working with minimum effort (there are a lot of such cases), So I came up with the idea of using Nokogiri to convert the `css` to `xpath`. I wanted to write it so that the above function can become

```
has_selector? xpath(:css, "#rightCol:contains(\"#{page_name}\")")
```

But since `xpath` has to return an array, I need to actually write this

```
has_selector?(*xpath(:css, "#rightCol:contains(\"#{page_name}\")"))
```

Is there a way to get the former behavior?

It can be assumed that right now `xpath` func is like the below, for brevity.

```
def xpath(*a)
  [1, 2]
end
```

Comment: Turns out it was only 5-6 places, so i just bit the bullet and took the 2nd form.

Comment: Capybara supports xpath natively, no need to hack that :) Check the doc for details.

Comment: @BillyChan am converting CSS to xpath since 2.0 does not use its own CSS driver, as i understand it.

Comment: Got it. I have not followed Capybara for months and am out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot let a method return multiple values. In order to do what you want, you have to change `has_selector?`, maybe something like this:

```
alias old_has_selector? :has_selector?
def has_selector? arg
  case arg
  when Array then old_has_selector?(*arg)
  else old_has_selector?(arg)
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. bit lower lvl than i wanted, but the only way to get it to work i guess

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has limited support for returning multiple values from a function. In particular a returned Array will get "destructured" when assigning to multiple variables:

```
def foo
  [1, 2]
end

a, b = foo
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

However in your case you need the splat (*) to make it clear you're not just passing the array as the first argument.

If you want a cleaner syntax, why not just write your own wrapper:

```
def has_xpath?(xp)
  has_selector?(*xpath(:css, xp))
end
```

Comment: Yup your form is cleaner, but I wanted to minimize change. Initially i was just going to convert the 2nd arg, but was hoping something like this might be possible and I just didnt know how..